# Parse CSV file to JSON after uploading using temporary copy

Tags: php, json, ajax, csv, ractivejs

I'm almost finishing building a functionality for parsing CSV files to JSON and just need help in piecing it together. The way it works is that files will be uploaded using AJAX/Jquery. Once the files has been uploaded and sent the PHP to parse the CSV file to JSON will then execute.

After parsing, the converted file will be push or sent to the API as a JSON object. Here is the code that I have been working. For the uploading i'm using this plugin [AJAX/JQuery File Uploader](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php)

This functionality is also built on using RactiveJS

**AJAX/Jquery File Uploader**

This is the section where I'm currently uploading or placing the file. URL is pointed at the `upload.php`.

```
<div id="fileuploader">Upload</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
        url: 'upload.php',
    });
})
</script>
```

---

**Uploads.php**

Is there a way to `GET` the temporary copy of the uploaded file and parse using the PHP code I have built below to convert the CSV to JSON

```
<?php

    if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br/>';
    }

    else {

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);

    }


?>
```

---

**PHP (CSV to JSON)**

Right now be the file is being declared manually.

```
<?php
    $json_data = csvToJson('lms.csv');
?>
```

---

```
<?php 


    function csvToJson($fname) {
        if (!($fp = fopen($fname, 'r') )) {
            die("Can't open file");
        }

        else {
            ('Upload File');
        }

        $key = fgetcsv($fp, "1024", ",");

        $json = array();
            while ($row = fgetcsv($fp, "1024", ",")) {
                $json[] = array_combine($key, $row);
        }

        fclose($fp);

        foreach ( $json as $k=>$v ) {

            $json[$k]['accountName']           =     $json[$k]['ACCOUNT NAME']; 
            $json[$k]['dateRequested']         =     $json[$k]['DATE']; 


            unset($json[$k]['ACCOUNT NAME']);
            unset($json[$k]['DATE']);

        }

        return json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

    }

 ?>

<?php // $target_file = fopen($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 'r'); ?>
```

**Send Converted to API (Ractive/AJAX/JS)**

As you can see the sending part is triggered by an on-click event `(app.on)`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ractive/0.9.0-build-48/ractive.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

var app = new Ractive({
    el       : '#container',
    template : '#template',
});


    var proxy       = 'http://192.168.1.126/lms-dev-noel/proxy.php';
    var endpoint    = 'account/leads/';
    var rt          = 'POST';
    var url         = proxy+'?endpoint='+endpoint+'&rt='+rt;

    var lms_json    = <?php echo json_encode($json_data); ?>;
    var jobjects    = JSON.parse(lms_json);


    for ( i = 0; i < jobjects.length; i++ ) {
        var data = jobjects[i];


        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
              type     : 'POST',
              url      : url,
              data     : data,
              dataType : 'json',
              success  : function() {

              },
              error    : function(error) {
                  console.log('Error')
              }

        });

    }



</script>
```

**Warning and Notices** 
[image]

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I'm trying to figure how I can get the path of the temporary file after being uploaded and store in a variable. So instead of manually setting the file path in this code  `$json_data = csvToJson('lms.csv');` i could just replace it with  `$json_data = csvToJson($filepath);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends a bit on where that csvToJson function is located in your code. If it's within uploads.php, or in a separate file that you can `include` in uploads.php, then you can just do:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);

$json_data = csvToJson('uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
echo $json_data;
```

Then in the script, change

```
var lms_json    = <?php echo json_encode($json_data); ?>;
```

to

```
var lms_json;
```

and move it to the top of your javascript.

It seems like you are trying to assign the variable before the API call has been made. Instead you need to capture the data from the the response of the uploadFile call (as per these docs: http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php):

```
$("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url: 'upload.php',
    onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr,pd)
    {
      //data: response from server
      lms_json = data;
    }
});
```

Comment: After trying your solution and making a test. The `JSON array` inside the `API` i'm connected to isn't passing the `JSON objects` that is being parsed. But there is a file inside the `uploads` directory

Comment: well you still need to do the `echo` statement as well to return it to the client. Did you not include that?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but which part or where should I place the `echo`?

Is this what you're pointing at? `var lms_json    = <?php echo json_encode($json_data); ?>;`

Comment: I don't think that will work - you seem to be assigning it before the ajax call to the API has run? I think you should echo it directly after you do the csvToJson call. Then the data will be returned to the "success" function of your ajax call.

Comment: Ok let me clarify, so basically i need to run the ajax inside the success function in order to make it run.

Comment: You have to assign the data inside the "success" callback of the upload call. The way you are doing it now assigns the data when the page is loaded, which is _before_ the upload has run and the data has actually been populated. I've edited the answer to hopefully make it clearer.